# In Jenkins job, behave tests stops after any failure

Tags: jenkins, bdd, python-behave

I have created a jenkins "freestyle" job, in which I am trying to run multiple BDD testing process. Following is the "commands" I have put in "Jenins/Build/execute shell" section:

```
    cd ~/FEXT_BETA_BDD
    rm -rf allure_reports  allure-reports  allure-results 
    pip install behave
    pip install selenium
    pip install -r features/requirements.txt

    # execute features in plan section
    behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -f pretty -o ./allure-reports 
        ./features/plan/*.feature

    # execute features in blueprint section
    behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -f pretty -o ./allure-reports 
        ./features/blueprint/*.feature
```

What I have found is in Jenkins, if there is any test case intermittent failure, such message is shown in the Console Output:

```
"
    ...
    0 features passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped
    0 scenarios passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped
    3 steps passed, 1 failed, 1 skipped, 0 undefined
    Took 2m48.770s
    Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
    "
```

And the leftover test cases are skipped.  But if I was to run the behave command on my local host directly, I don't get this type of behaviour. The failure will be detected and the remaining test cases continues till all are finished.

So How may I work around this issue in Jenkins ?

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following syntax:

```
set +e

# execute features in plan section
behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -f pretty -o ./allure-reports 
        ./features/plan/*.feature || echo 'ALERT: Build failed while running the plan section'

# execute features in blueprint section
behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -f pretty -o ./allure-reports 
        ./features/blueprint/*.feature || echo 'ALERT: Build failed while running the blueprint section'

# Restoring original configuration
set -e
```

Note:

- Goal of [set -e](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) is to cause the shell to abort any time an error occurs. If you will see your log output, you will notice `sh -xe` at the start of execution which confirms that `Execute Shell` in Jenkins uses `-e` option. So, to disable it, you can use `+e` instead. However, it's good to restore it once your purpose is fulfilled so that subsequent commands produce expected result.

Ref: https://superuser.com/questions/1113014/what-would-set-e-and-set-x-commands-do-in-the-context-of-a-shell-script

Answer (score 1):

The ConsoleOutput from the SummaryReporter above indicates that you have only one feature with one scenario (that fails). Behave has no such thing that it stops when the first scenario fails.

An early abortion of the test run can only occur if critical things happen:

- A failure/exception in the `before_all()` hook occurs
- A critical exception is raised (SystemExit, KeyboardInterrupt) to end the test run
- Your implementation tells behave to abort the test run (make sense on critical failures when all other tests will also fail; why waste the time)

**BUT:** If the test run is aborted early, all the features/scenarios that are not executed yet are reported as **untested counts** in the SummaryReporter.

```sh
...
0 features passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped, 2 untested
0 scenarios passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped, 3 untested
0 steps passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped, 0 undefined, 6 untested
```

HINT: Untested counts are normally hidden. They are only shown if the counter is not zero (greater than zero).

This is not the case in your description.

SEE ALSO:

- [behave: features/runner.abort_by_user.feature](https://github.com/behave/behave/blob/master/features/runner.abort_by_user.feature)